# Is it possible to combine a Bootstrap theme with an existing custom Drupal 6 theme?

Tags: 6, theming

Is it possible to combine a Bootstrap theme with an existing custom Drupal 6 theme?

I want to use [Grayscale](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/) in my Drupal 6 website. But I already have an existing custom theme and I am not sure if I can simply use it. Or whether the styling will interfere with other stylesheets in Drupal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) base theme for D7 (and even an upcoming D8 version), which bridges the gap between Drupal and the [Bootstrap Framework](http://getbootstrap.com/), with also quite a few (contributed) sub-themes available for it already.

So if your question was about D7, then it seems such combination that you're looking for should be possible. As you may know already, the [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) base is not available for D6. But maybe you can use the D7-version of it as inspiration to somehow make such combination also work for D6. Ultimately even come up with a backport of the [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) base theme for D6?

**Note**: as mentioned by [Molot](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/16495/mo%C5%82ot)'s in the comment to this answer, there is "some" [D6 backport of it available on github](https://github.com/sdmunoz/Drupal-6-Theme-Bootstrap) ... Via Drupal.org there doesn't seem to be any D6 versions, however there "is" [some D5 version](https://www.drupal.org/node/259850) of it also ... Maybe upgrading the D5 version to D6 is another approach to consider? Using [Browse code repository](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bootstrap) only results in D7/D8 versions though ...

Comment: Backport [is on github](https://github.com/sdmunoz/Drupal-6-Theme-Bootstrap) - I don't know it's quality, I just see it's there.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks for the hint @Mołot !!!